# Как добавить UIView в текущий View Controller?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

В ViewController имеется в Segmented Control.
В зависимости от его значения необходимо в этом же окне подгружать окна.
Как все правильно организовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала идем в дкументацию и читаем что пишет apple [тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)
потом можно посмотреть примеры того как это делают другие. например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views)

делаем выводы. пишем то, что нужно в данной конкретной задаче.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Посмотрел тему на SO. Появились вопросы:
1. Как я понял "firstView и secondView" - это View Controller's со своими xib-ами?
2. Если это так, то как правильно расположить эти VC в текущем окне? т.к. они не должны полностью его перекрывать.

Идея такая: есть окно настроек. В нем segmented control со значениями Клиент и Водитель. В зависимости от выбранного значения - внизу загружаются соответствующие поля для Клиента или Водителя. 
Только начал изучать iOS-разработку. Поэтому даже не знаю с какой стороны подойти к этому вопросу.

Comment: firstView и secondView -  это как раз ваши UIView.

Comment: в .xib файле имеются firstView и secondView. в .h-файле они объявлены как IBOutlet и property.
В реализации при изменении значения segmented control пытаюсь менять [clientView setHidden:NO];
[driverView setHidden:YES]; - но ничего не происходит.

Comment: Сорри, ошибка найдена: забыл добавить вьюшки в @synthesize

Comment: вот рабочий пример https://github.com/crafterm/SegmentedControlRevisited

Comment: Спасибо за помощь:)